# How to deploy my Java EE project

Tags: java, eclipse, web, deployment, glassfish

I have finished my Java EE project. The thing is I don't know to deploy it to a web server. The thing is the code is adapted to the GlassFish server Data Pool. Will this be a problem when deploying and how to deploy it? Using eclipse in Ubuntu 14.04.03. Java 1.8.0_66.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the documentation:
[Deploying and Undeploying Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/6nmni99aj/index.html)

to undeploy you need use command undeploy

```
glassfish/bin/asadmin undeploy Test
```

to deploy, usually you need copy your **war** file into **autodeploy**
folder

here's my script to deploy test.war file

```
set gfver=4.1

del "E:\Program Files\glassfish-%gfver%\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy\Test.war_deployed"
del "E:\Program Files\glassfish-%gfver%\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy\Test.war"
del "E:\Program Files\glassfish-%gfver%\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy\.autodeploystatus\Test.war"

del "E:\Program Files\glassfish-%gfver%\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\Test\.glassfishStaleFiles"

copy "E:\workspace\TestProject\dist\Test.war" "E:\Program Files\glassfish-%gfver%\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy"
```